# Diferença entre base_url(); e base_url('assets/example');?>

Tags: php, codeigniter

Qual seria a diferença entre elas ? Pois em meu projeto utilizei ambas e não consegui identificar a diferença.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Muito simples, base_url() no codeigniter retorna a url base, digamos que seu site seja: http://meusite.com.br vc chamando a função base_url() irá retornar isso.

Se você passar o parâmetro, ela vai retornar a base + parâmetro, exemplo:
digamos que você queira acessar um artigo do seu blog.

```
echo base_url("blog/post/123");
```

http://meusite.com.br/blog/post/123

Para mais informações acesse https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#base_url